# How to load local scripts on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**CODE:**

app.js

```
//Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
```

section1/index.ejs

```
<script src="/public/js/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/angularfire.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

Error 404 for all those files when I load section1/index.ejs

What is missing ? What mistake have I made ?

Comment: I think you have to omit the first "/"

Comment: @yBrodsky That was not it :/

Comment: From both the static folder declaration and the script tags

Comment: @yBrodsky It sadly did not work :(

Comment: Seems like you have duplicated `public`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a first argument to [`app.use`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use), which will be the public path.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then on the client:

```
<script src="/js/firebase.js"></script>
```

You can also use `/public` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));`

And I think if you want to use it as a middleware without a virtual path, you should use it like this:

`app.use(express.static('public'));`

Without defining the whole path, Express will get the folder for you automatically.